# Create button spinner when clicked in angular 6 without service call

Tags: angular

I want to show and hide spinner when i download the pdf file.
My code is as below:-This is my Html component code

```
<div >
              <ng-container *ngFor="let p of selectedStudent.photos.list;let i = index">
                <div *ngIf="p.eventName === 'FLIPBOOK'; then ifcondition "></div>
                <ng-template #ifcondition>
                  <div class="flipbook-img" >
                    <button class="btn btn-primary isLoadSpring" [disabled]="isLoadingSpring" (click)="downloadMyFile(selectedStudent.schoolId)">
                  <!--<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>-->
                  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" *ngIf="isLoadingSpring"></i>Download                   
                </button>
                    <img [src]="getImageForFlipBook(1,p.imageUrl,p.rotationAngle,300)" class="photoimges" />
                  </div>
                </ng-template>
              </ng-container>
            </div>
```

My .ts code.

```
downloadMyFile(id: number) {
this.isLoadingSpring = true;
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
link.setAttribute('href', '/assets/files/' + id + '/Year-Book.pdf');
link.setAttribute('download', 'Year-Book.pdf');
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
link.remove();
```

}

when i click button spinner is a display and file is download but still my sppiner is not stop . Kindly help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unset this.isLoadingSpring after link removal.

```
downloadMyFile(id: number) {
    this.isLoadingSpring = true;
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    link.setAttribute('href', '/assets/files/' + id + '/Year-Book.pdf');
    link.setAttribute('download', 'Year-Book.pdf');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();

    this.isLoadingSpring = false;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had done changes in my code :

```
async downloadMyFile(id: number) {
    this.isLoadingSpring = true;
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    link.setAttribute('href', '/assets/files/' + id + '/Year-Book.pdf');
    await link.setAttribute('download', 'Year-Book.pdf');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
    await this.delay(3000);
    this.isLoadingSpring = false;
  }

  private delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
```